# What version of RHEL am I using?

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, rhel6, rhel4

From the shell and without root privileges, how can I determine what Red Hat Enterprise Linux version I'm running?

Ideally, I'd like to get both the major and minor release version, for example RHEL 4.0 or RHEL 5.1, etc.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use the `lsb_release` command on various Linux distributions:

```
lsb_release -i -r
```

This will tell you the Distribution and Version and is a little bit more accurate than accessing files that may or may not have been modified by the admin or a software package. As well as working across multiple distros.

For RHEL, you should use:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Comment: command not found on my CentOS 5.4 box :(

Comment: @gbjbaanb: That's strange I tested it on a fresh 5.4 minimal install and it worked just fine...

Comment: `lsb_release -i -r`
-bash: lsb_release: command not found. However, 
`cat /etc/redhat-release`
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

Comment: Just for the record: Does not work on RHEL 6.5 minimal install. Command lsb_release is nowhere to be found.

Comment: lsb_release is not a lightweight package, It pulls in CUPS to provide ‘/usr/bin/lp’, which pulls in some pdf translation goop, which pulls in some rendering libraries...

Comment: "For RHEL, you should use..."  And after all, this question is specifically about RHEL...

Answer (score 143):

You can look at the contents of /etc/redhat-release, which will look something like this:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
```

The contents are different for an actual RHEL system.  This technique works on all RedHat derivatives, including CentOS, Fedora, and others.

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: `lsb_release` is the first thing to try, but since that might not be installed looking at files is a good Plan B.

Comment: @chicks Given that the question asks for a test for Redhat systems, and lsb_release is not installed by default on redhat systems and /etc/redhat-release is, then  lsb_release is obviously not the first thing to try!

Comment: @bye It is the first thing to try (at least in my opinion) , you always try the things which should be common on all distributions first, then only you switch to distribution-specific solutions.

Answer (score 25):

I prefer to use the /etc/issue file.

```
$ cat /etc/issue
```

I've seen many situations where /etc/redhat-release has been modified to meet software compatibility requirements (Dell or HP's management agents, for instance).

Comment: `/etc/issue` also works on other OSes as well, such as Debian & Ubuntu, and works with Linux OSes that don't conform to the Linux Standards Base, and lightweight OSes that don't have the lsb* utilities installed.

Comment: This is not reliable. Apparently `/etc/issue` is meant to be parsed by [agetty](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/logon.html), which replaces the escape sequences with proper information. If you just `cat` it, the result may be underwhelming. On Fedora, one gets `Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)`, which tells you something but on RHEL7, one just gets `\S Kernel \r on an \m`.

Comment: Note that `/etc/issue` may be replaced by the local admin and hence is not a reliable source of information.

Answer (score 13):

The most reliable way **when** `lsb_release` **is not installed** is:

```
# rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' redhat-release-server
6Server

# rpm -q --queryformat '%{RELEASE}' redhat-release-server
6.4.0.4.el6
```

On minimal installs, `lsb_release` is missing.

To get this working also with Red Hat clones (credit goes to comments):

```
# rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' $(rpm -qa '(redhat|sl|slf|centos|oraclelinux)-release(|-server|-workstation|-client|-computenode)')
```

Or, as a single command (rather than two "rpm"'s being executed):

```
# rpm -qa --queryformat '%{VERSION}\n' '(redhat|sl|slf|centos|oraclelinux)-release(|-server|-workstation|-client|-computenode)'
```

Use `sed`/`cut` and other text manipulating UNIX tools to get what you want.

Comment: This seems to work, more generically:  

`rpm -qa  '(oraclelinux|sl|redhat|centos)-release(|-server)'`

sl is for Scientific Linux; if you know the right name for other RHEL rebuilds maybe comment below.  Warning - not extensively tested.

Comment: Yeah thanks, one note: does not work with RHEL Worstation.

Comment: One note - this runs a lot slower than parsing /etc/foo-release.

Comment: or `rpm -qa | grep release` is even easier

Answer (score 6):

Assuming it truly is a Red Hat release (not Centos):

```
rpm -q redhat-release
```

Or just run:

```
uname -r
```

And map the output.  2.6.9 kernels are RHEL4, 2.6.18 kernels are RHEL5.  If necessary, you can map the full version to the specific update releases from Red Hat (i.e. 2.6.9-89 is RHEL5 U4).

Comment: `rpm -q redhat-release` just returns `package redhat-release is not installed` for me, and `uname -r` just tells me the kernel release.

Comment: Oh ! And now that time has passed, what would be RHEL6 ? RHEL7 ? Hum... Here are the answers: https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL7

Answer (score 3):

I quite like using the `/etc/os-release` file, which is in the release RPM:

```
# yum whatprovides /etc/os-release 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: dl.za.jsdaav.net
 * extras: dl.za.jsdaav.net
 * updates: dl.za.jsdaav.net
centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64 : CentOS Linux release file
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/os-release

centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64 : CentOS Linux release file
Repo        : @anaconda
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/os-release
```

This file can be sourced in scripts, like:

```
$ source /etc/os-release
$ echo $NAME
CentOS Linux
$ echo $VERSION
7 (Core)
```

Comment: Interesting, useful.  Unfortunately, not present on RHEL6 so of limited value at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `hostnamectl`:

```
$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: xxxxxx.xxx.xxx
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
        Machine ID: 3e3038756eaf4c5c954ec3d24f35b13f
           Boot ID: 958452e0088b4191a4ea676ebc90403b
  Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just get the version numbers the following is about as short and simple as I can get it.

Tested on rhel 6.7, rhel 7.2, debian 8.3 and ubuntu 14.04:

```
lsb_release -s -r | cut -d '.' -f 1
```

For a practical example, say you want to test for the distribution major and minor version and do things based on that:

```
#!/bin/bash

major=$(lsb_release -s -r | cut -d '.' -f 1)
minor=$(lsb_release -s -r | cut -d '.' -f 2)

if (( "$major" >= 7 ))
then
  echo "Do stuff, OS major version is $major"
  echo "OS minor version is $minor"
else
  echo "Do other things"
  echo "Your version is $major.$minor"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

A late arrival to this, but I had fun trying to figure out the RHEL version on several remote nodes. So, if you have a batch of servers that use the same password (I know, I know...) here is a quick and dirty to check the RedHat version:

**Create an expect script**

```
vim server-version.sh
```

**Expect script to check major RedHat version on multiple remote hosts**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
log_user 0
spawn ssh -l root [lindex $argv 0]
expect "assword:"
send "sUp3rS3cr3tP4ssW0rd^\r"
expect "# "
log_user 1
send "cat /etc/redhat-release\r"
expect "*#"
log_user 0
send "exit\n"
```

**Run the script for all your nodes**

```
[root@home ~]#
for server in server1 server2 server3 server4 server5; do echo -e "$server: \c"; /root/server-version.sh $server; echo; echo; done;
```

**Output**

```
server1: cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
[root@server1 ~]#

server2: cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
[root@server2 ~]#

...
```

Comment: If you're going to do remote stuff on a lot of machines, I strongly recommend using Ansible rather than hand-rolled bash scripts.

Comment: I also recommend not enabling root login over ssh