# How to truly find out release version of red hat?

Tags: redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What version of RHEL am I using?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89654/what-version-of-rhel-am-i-using)

I would like to find out the true and actual release version of Red Hat OS.

I know that catting /etc/redhat-release file is a popular solution...but what if somebody had tweaked that file to allow some software installation like Oracle?

In such a case, I would be getting wrong information.

Is "more /proc/version" most reliable way?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/89654/what-version-of-rhel-am-i-using

Comment: Thanks! From that post it looks like lsb_release is the command that can fetch version info from source of truth..

Answer (score 1):

I always use `cat /etc/*release` -- works for most (all?) distros.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `/etc/issue`, as `/etc/*release` files are sometimes modified to meet software compatibility requirements (Dell or HP's management agents, for instance).